# Computing a circular-linear partial correlation

Tags: correlation, residuals, pearson-r, circular-statistics

The `CircStats` toolbox for MATLAB (http://bit.ly/18C1SCF) implements a procedure to compute a correlation between a linear and a circular variable. Specifically, the correlation between a linear variable $x$ and a circular variable $\alpha$ is given by
$$\rho_{\textrm{cl}} = \sqrt{\frac{r^2_{\textrm{cx}}+r^2_{\textrm{sx}}- 2r_{\textrm{cx}}r_{\textrm{sx}}r_{\textrm{cs}}}{1-r^2_{\textrm{cs}}}},$$
where $r_\textrm{sx}$ is the Pearson correlation coefficient between $\sin\alpha$ and $x$, $r_\textrm{cx}$ is the coefficient between $\cos\alpha$ and $x$, and $r_\textrm{cs}$ is the coefficient between $\cos\alpha$ and $\sin\alpha$.

How do I compute the partial correlation of $x$ and $\alpha$, given a third variable, $y$ (linear), as a control variable?

Comment: Are you referring to the R [CircStats](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CircStats/index.html) package?

Comment: @chl, no, MATLAB.

Comment: Is it enough to replace each linear correlation in the formula with a partial correlation, with $y$ as a control variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\rho_{cl}$ is just the ordinary multiple correlation of $x$ with $\sin \alpha$ and $\cos \alpha$. To control for $y$, partial it out of $x$, $\sin \alpha$, and $\cos \alpha$, then get the multiple correlation using the regression residuals.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the same as replacing each correlation in the formula for $\rho_{cl}$ with the corresponding partial correlation with $y$ as a control variable?

Comment: Yes, it's that easy.